# Perl LWP::Simple::getstore How to check if the file exists in destination directory

Tags: perl, file, exists

In my Perl script I am using `LWP::Simple::getstore` to retrieve an image and store as file. But before storing how to check if that file already exists?

this is the snippet

```
use constant FILE_DIR => "/home/destination/files/";
my $image_path = FILE_FOLDER."$item_id"."_"."$file_date.$image";
my $res = LWP::Simple::getstore($image_url,$image_path);
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: `FILE_DIR` **and** `FILE_FOLDER`? That sounds confusing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [file test](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html), e.g.

```
unless (-e $image_path) {
    LWP::Simple::getstore($image_url, $image_path); 
}
```